# How can I reset the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) back to defaults?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Having played with WSL over several releases, I find that I'm getting various strange errors and inconsistencies.

I would like to reset the WSL environment back to defaults - what is the best way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UPDATE 2023-01-06: You can use unregister on WSL v2 as well. You can also reset a distro from the add/remove programmes app.

---

WSL v1 is made up of 2 parts. WSL itself and the Linux distribution(s) you install.

You can reset any distribution that you have installed by using the following command (from W10 1903):

```
wsl --unregister <DistributionName>
```

You can then reinstall the distribution by finding it in the Windows store and clicking on "Launch".

Note that, prior to W10 1903, you need to use the wslconfig.exe - 1903 merges the commands from that into wsl.exe.

If you need to also reset WSL, you will need to uninstall it then reinstall. WSL is a Windows feature so you can add/remove it using the appropriate settings or control panel entry.

References:

- [Microsoft Docs for WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/about)
- [Using WSL with VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) - also gives some useful configuration

Note that WSL v2 has been announced but no details are yet available. It is a totally different architecture to v1 so expect resetting that to be slightly different.